# Is there a way to change the default directory for PBS output and error files while retaining the default names?

Tags: pbs

As the title says, when I submit PBS jobs, they always create the output and error files in the current working directory. I would like to specify the directory in the PBS script file using the `#PBS -o`  line. I can specify the directory with a file name, like

```
#PBS -o /path/to/my/outputfile.txt
```

but I can't figure out how to keep the filename as it is by default. Using

```
#PBS -o /path/to/my/$PBS_JOBNAME.o$PBS_JOBID
#PBS -o /path/to/my/${PBS_JOBNAME}.o${PBS_JOBID}
```

Don't work, and changing only the directory results in a different filename that doesn't contain the job name.